# Long.parseLong throws NumberFormatException for binary string

Tags: java, types, binary-string

we have byte `string s = "1111000000000111000000000001000000000010010000000000000000000000"`(this value equal -1150951111012646912), if we use `Long.parseLong(s, 2)`, we got "

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
> "1100000001000000010000000100000000001110000000010000010000000000"
> under radix 2".

i fixed this problem with this way to convert

```
 new BigInteger(s, 2).longValue();
```

Explain please i can't understand what happend?

Same situation with this value:
`s = 1100000001000000010000000100000000001110000000010000010000000000` (equal -4593600976060873728)

```
new BigInteger(s, 2).longValue();
```

Comment: since you are *not* providing the negative sign, try `Long.parseUnsignedLong("1111000000000111000000000001000000000010010000000000000000000000",2)` (it will return a negative `long` for above strings)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that neither `Integer.parseInt` nor `Long.parseLong` can parse twos complement negative numbers without replacing the sign bit with an explicit `'+'` or `'-'` sign.

This is probably in keeping with parsing a decimal number such as the following:

```
String max = "9223372036854775807";  // Long.MAX_VALUE         
String maxPlus1 = "9223372036854775808"; // Long.MAX_VALUE+1 
long m = Long.parseLong(max,10); //OK
long m1 =Long.parseLong(maxPlus1,10)); // throws exception
```

To parse your two's complement value of long or any other value you can use
[Long.parseUnsignedLong](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#parseUnsignedLong(java.lang.String,int)).  All the following three method calls correctly parse the values, printing out `Long.MIN_VALUE`, the fourth one being your specific value in your question.

```
System.out.println(Long.parseUnsignedLong("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",2));
System.out.println(Long.parseUnsignedLong("8000000000000000",16));
System.out.println(Long.parseUnsignedLong("9223372036854775808",10));
System.out.println(Long.parseUnsignedLong("1111000000000111000000000001000000000010010000000000000000000000",2));
```

prints

```
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
-1150951111012646912
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in a size 64 binary string, which is bigger than the signed byte size of a long. Since `parseLong` doesn't accept unsigned binary representations and instead wants a - or (an optional) + in front of the number to denote the sign, it throws an error. The max byte length you can pass into parseLong is 63.

An equivalent `parseLong` call to your first example would be `Long.parseLong("-111111111000111111111110111111111101110000000000000000000000", 2)`, using the - sign and the two's complement of the number.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse a 64-bit unsigned (long) integer as a 64-bit signed (long) integer.

Java's `long` is not unsigned. You will only be able to store a positive number up to 63 bits. The max value for a `long` is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` or `2^(63)`.

The most-significant bit (left-most) is the signed bit.

- If it's a 64-bit string that begins with a 1, it's negative.
- If it's less than 64 bits, it's positive and the leading 0 will not be displayed.

Note: Any leading zeroes will not be displayed.

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class NumberUtils {

  static final String MIN_SIGNED_LONG_BINARY = Long.toBinaryString(Long.MIN_VALUE);
  static final String MAX_SIGNED_LONG_BINARY =
      padStart(Long.toBinaryString(Long.MAX_VALUE), 64, "0");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    parseBinary("1111000000000111000000000001000000000010010000000000000000000000");
    parseBinary("1100000001000000010000000100000000001110000000010000010000000000");
  }

  private static void parseBinary(String str) {
    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(str, 2);
    System.out.println(bigInt.longValue());
    try {
      Long.parseLong(str, 2);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.printf(
          "Error:%n* Min: %s (%d bits)%n* Val: %s (%d bits)%n* Max: %s (%d bits)%n",
          MIN_SIGNED_LONG_BINARY,
          MIN_SIGNED_LONG_BINARY.length(),
          str,
          str.length(),
          MAX_SIGNED_LONG_BINARY,
          MAX_SIGNED_LONG_BINARY.length());
    }
  }

  public static String padStart(String inputString, int targetLength, String padString) {
    if (inputString.length() >= targetLength) return inputString;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (sb.length() < targetLength - inputString.length()) {
      sb.append(padString);
    }
    return sb.append(inputString).toString();
  }
}
```

### Output

```
-1150951111012646912
Error:
* Min: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (64 bits)
* Val: 1111000000000111000000000001000000000010010000000000000000000000 (64 bits)
* Max: 0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 (64 bits)
-4593600976060873728
Error:
* Min: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (64 bits)
* Val: 1100000001000000010000000100000000001110000000010000010000000000 (64 bits)
* Max: 0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 (64 bits)
```